# Horizontal Display on Gnome

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I'm stuck trying to find a way to get the login screen to display horizintally upon bootup. I'd prefer the login page on the monitor on the left but whatever.

Any ideas here? I'm using Gnome

[image]

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: `I'd prefer the login page on the monitor on the left` ... switch the video cables